# os_log debug is visible for external developer when distributing a framework

Tags: ios, swift, logging, xcframework, oslog

**Setup:**

- Build job generates Frameworks in Release configuration
- Frameworks are packaged into an XCFramework
- XCFramework is distributed to an external developer who integrates it with their app.

**Problem:** The external developer can see the logs originating from my framework in plain text when running the app in iOS Simulator.

**Sample code**

```
            private static let log = OSLog(subsystem: Constants.loggingSubsystem, category: String(describing: FrameworkName.self))
...
...
            os_log("Network response: %@", log: Self.log, type: .debug, String(describing: response))
            os_log("Network response data: %{private}@",
                   log: Self.log,
                   type: .debug,
                   String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

**Expected output:** nothing, as both of the calls are set to be `debug`, so they should not produce any output in the Release build.

At least, the 2nd call should not show the network response data in plain text.

**Observed output:** Network response & data are printed in plain text for the external developer.

Comment: Why would you think that the logs would be suppressed when the developer is running a debug build?

Comment: Because the framework has been built for distribution with the Release configuration.

Comment: A release build doesn't remove the log statements. The output of the log statements is just filtered when the overall project is running in release mode. If you don't want the debug logging in your release framework you need to use `#if debug...` to remove the log statements from the release build altogether.

Comment: Thank you, could you please post this as an answer and I will accept it. Btw, is this a documented behavior by Apple somewhere?